# Spring-MVC, Hibernate, Postgres : Searching in database with multiple variables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to search in the database for a combination of options which the user selects. So let's say that there are 10 options, and if user selects 7 of them, how can I effectively write a single method in DAO with a single query which can adapt to the number of options. Kindly see the image below :

[image: Ebay search]

As you can see on the left hand side, there are multiple options and the user can select whichever the user chooses. I am looking for something similar where I have created a Search object entity and this entity I would like to pass to dao, where its variables will be extracted and search executed in database.

But if there are even like 3 variables, I see the query looking as :

Pseudo code :

```
public ResultObject doSearch(var1, var3, var3){
if((var1==true)){
// hibernate query for search where var1 equals true
}
if(!(var2==null)&&(var1==true)){
//Hibernate query for search where var2 is set by user and var1 is true
}
}
```

But if I keep it doing it in such a horrible fashion, I will never finish. What is the way to handle multiple variables for search when only the ones set should be included and others discarded. Kindly let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder. As long as the variables are independent from each other this should be easier.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("FROM phone WHERE 1=1 ");


if (var1) {
    sb.append(" AND var1 = :var1");
}

if (var2) {
    sb.append(" AND var2 = :var2 ");
}

sb.toString();
```

Comment: This looks promising, I presume I can use it for boolean as well, and others. Yes, they are independent, I have created an Object model for them as I also need to save the search history. Still seems a bit manual, I had thought there might be some advanced mechanism as there might be projects out there which have 50-60 search parameters or more, then this would get tedious.